# Android Action Bar not working on cellphone

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In Android Studio my action bar is green. When i am testing the app in my cell phone the action bar back to default style...

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 mini and the code is

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#7FBF50</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.Title</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Edit your post and include how you apply the style, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered a similar problem when I developed for tablets vs. phones. It could be that you have multiple value directories in your build for different screen sizes, especially since its a S4 mini which has an unusual size. Try to remove extra "value*" directories in your res directory that correspond to your device's screen size (or remove them all except for the default one if you want to have the same style across device screen sizes).